# How to remove a blank and dead link/icon from Dash search

Tags: unity-dash

[image~~~](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k30fy.png)

I installed Pycharm-community in a wrong way

```
sudo ./pycharm.sh
```

now I remove its entire program directory and ~/.Pycharm50 config directory.

The problem is a invalid icon still appears in the Dash search result

I already tried

```
ls ~/.local/share/applications | grep pycharm
sudo ls /usr/share/applications | grep pycharm
```

but I got nothing.

I also rebooted but it is still there.

Comment: try this `sudo find / -type f -iname '*pycharm*'`

Comment: Delete that file

Comment: Logout and log back in

Comment: If solved, write the solution. ("answer your question to share your knowledge in Q&A format")

Answer (score 0):

another file `~/.local/share/applications/jna_jar.desktop` also need to be deleted. It seems to be openjdk brought by first time running pycharm.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Welcome to PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=jna_jar.png
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:./../lib/boot.jar -classpath ./../lib/bootstrap.jar:./../lib/extensions.jar:./../lib/util.jar:./../lib/jdom.jar:./../lib/log4j.jar:./../lib/trove4j.jar:./../lib/jna.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=./pycharm64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/x/java_error_in_PYCHARM_%p.log -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=PyCharm50 -Didea.platform.prefix=PyCharmCore -Didea.no.jre.check=true com.intellij.idea.Main
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

---

Several points done in the question was wrong.

1) Running `sudo ls /usr/share/applications` with sudo is nonsense. Your user can read the data. How do
you think you get the icons in Dash? Think about it instead of wildly
adding sudo to commands when you don't get what you expect.

2) The files in /usr/share/applications define the files using
configuration lines in the files. The filename has no bearing here. You
could rename them all to random letters and numbers and Dash would still
work as it does now.

3) Try `grep -i pycharm /usr/share/applications/*` to find out what should be deleted